# PyMySQL not doing insertion as expected

Tags: python, mysql, insertion

I have a table lucene_try which looks like this:

```
id || title    || comment
1  || Title 1  || Sentence 1 of Comment 1. Sentence 2 of Comment 1. 
2  || Title 1  || Sentence 1 of Comment 2. Sentence 2 of Comment 2.
```

What I am trying to achieve is for each title, and each comment of the title, break the comment into different sentences and put it in a different table which must look like this in lucene_rs:

```
id || title    || root_comment   || sub_comment
1  || Title 1  || Comment 1      || Sentence 1 
2  || Title 1  || Comment 1      || Sentence 2 
3  || Title 1  || Comment 2      || Sentence 1 
4  || Title 1  || Comment 2      || Sentence 2
```

I have written the code for this, and it works properly when I print it on the console/terminal. It prints Sentence 1 and Sentence 2 of Comment 1 as well as Comment 2. However, when I want to insert this data, it only prints and inserts Sentence 1 and Sentence 2 of Comment 1.

Here is my code:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
from nltk import tokenize
import pdb

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='password', db='master_thesis', autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM lucene_counter WHERE count > 5 AND count <= 30")

lucene_rs_list = list()

for row in cursor:
    lucene_rs_list.append(row[1])

random.shuffle(lucene_rs_list)
final_list = lucene_rs_list[:1]

for i in range(len(final_list)):
    current_title = final_list[i]
    query = "SELECT title, comment FROM lucene_try WHERE title = %s"
    cursor.execute(query, final_list[i])
    for row in cursor:
        root_comment = BeautifulSoup(row[1], "lxml").text
        print("Root Title: ", current_title)
        print("Root Comment: ", root_comment)
        cleancomment = tokenize.sent_tokenize(root_comment)
        for j in range(len(cleancomment)):
            # THIS LINE PRINTS EVERYTHING PROPERLY WITH ALL THE COMMENTS AND SUBCOMMENTS IF CURSOR.EXECUTE IS COMMENTED OUT
            print("Sub Comment: ", cleancomment[j])
            # IF THE CURSOR.EXECUTE IS UNCOMMENTED, IT ONLY DISPLAYS RESULT OF THE FIRST ROOT_COMMENT AND NOT ALL
            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO lucene_rs (title, root_comment, comment) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s")""" % (current_title, root_comment, cleancomment[j]))
        print("\n")

conn.close()
```

Comment: Don't comment out the code you want us to help with. SO's code highlighting makes it hard to read.

Comment: Hey Barmar, I have uncommented the cursor.execute(INSERT) statement. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same cursor to execute the `INSERT` query as you're using to get the results of the `SELECT` query. When you execute the `INSERT`, it no longer contains the results of the `SELECT`, so the next iteration of the loop stops.

Either read all the results of the `SELECT` into a list and then loop over that, or use a different cursor for the `INSERT`.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='password', db='master_thesis', autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM lucene_counter WHERE count > 5 AND count <= 30")

lucene_rs_list = list()

for row in cursor:
    lucene_rs_list.append(row[1])

random.shuffle(lucene_rs_list)
final_list = lucene_rs_list[:1]

for i in range(len(final_list)):
    current_title = final_list[i]
    query = "SELECT title, comment FROM lucene_try WHERE title = %s"
    cursor.execute(query, final_list[i])
    for row in cursor:
        root_comment = BeautifulSoup(row[1], "lxml").text
        print("Root Title: ", current_title)
        print("Root Comment: ", root_comment)
        cleancomment = tokenize.sent_tokenize(root_comment)
        for j in range(len(cleancomment)):
            # THIS LINE PRINTS EVERYTHING PROPERLY WITH ALL THE COMMENTS AND SUBCOMMENTS IF CURSOR.EXECUTE IS COMMENTED OUT
            print("Sub Comment: ", cleancomment[j])
            # IF THE CURSOR.EXECUTE IS UNCOMMENTED, IT ONLY DISPLAYS RESULT OF THE FIRST ROOT_COMMENT AND NOT ALL
            cursor2.execute("""INSERT INTO lucene_rs (title, root_comment, comment) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s")""" % (current_title, root_comment, cleancomment[j]))
        print("\n")

conn.close()
```

Comment: This works like a charm, and that was really something silly from my side. Thanks a ton Barmar.